# Sugar ORM dropping a column on updating database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, sugarorm

I'm using Sugar ORM in my project. I need to drop a column in a sqlite table in my next version of the app. I have checked out the documentation on Sugar ORM migration, but I can't find the way for dropping a column in it.

Answer (score 2):

Because `android-sugarorm` (`sugarorm`) uses `SQLite` underneath, it is not possible use `ALTER TABLE` to remove a column (field), so it is not done automatically.

> `SQLite` supports a limited subset of `ALTER TABLE`. The `ALTER TABLE` command in `SQLite` allows the user to rename a table or to add a new column to an existing table. It is not possible to rename a column, remove a column, or add or remove constraints from a table.

[ALTER TABLE SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html)

In `SQLite` you can:

(1). create new table as the one you are trying to change (without the column to delete)
(2). copy all data (except the column you want to delete)
(3). drop old table
(4). rename the new table, to the old name.

See also [Migrating database from previous version](http://satyan.github.io/sugar/migration.html)
[SQLite FAQ](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q11)

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

- Create a folder named sugar_upgrades in your assets folder
- Create a file named <version>.sql in that folder, which corresponds
  to the database version. eg. 1.sql, 2.sql This file would contain all
  the **update/alter queries** for that particular version.
- Change the VERSION metadata field in AndroidManifest.xml to the
  appropriate version

For more details check [sugar migration](http://satyan.github.io/sugar/migration.html)

Comment: add and update column can be done in above steps. but can we do dropping a column?

Comment: Not sure but you can try it, it's also an alteration in table

Comment: Were you able to drop the column?

Comment: @nandha-dev Were you able to drop a column? We're also facing the same dilemma on our project. I tried ignoring a column without changing the current database version. It's not throwing any exception and when I checked the db, the column is still there.

Comment: @PenguinBlues I could not drop the column. I did a work around having some default value in the field and fixed the issue.